# Display results of mySql LEFT OUTER JOIN in another row

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two table Customers and Children with multiple fields in mySql DB, related by One to Many relationship so a customers could have 0 to n children.

I've to extract all the children foreach customers in a new row under the main customer row.

Is this possible?

This is the query:

```
select customers.FIELDS...
from customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN asg_children 
ON customers.id = children.customer_id 
where customers.first_name != 'DEFAULT' and  customers.first_name != '' and 
customers.first_name != '_'
order by customers.last_name asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create this doing the following with an order by column. The dots is where you put your columns, and they must be the same in each query. This makes assumption a customerid in children must exist in customer. If not added the in statement following. Note you can add your own name filters as you require, I have left them out

```
Select *
From
(

  Select ID customerid ,.......,1 ordby From customer
  Union all
  Select customer_id,.......,2 from children /* optional in clause here */
 ) x
 Order by customerid,ordby
```

Optional in clause

```
Where customer_id in (select Id from customer)
```